# Example of function that is not differentiable at certain point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need an example of a function $\displaystyle f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ such that $f$ is differentiable everywhere except at the point $(1, 2)$.

I was thinking (similar to single variable functions) about using the absolute value, for an example $\displaystyle f(x,y) = (|x-1|, |x-2|)$ but I'm not sure if that is correct. Could, as an analogy, a norm be used? Something like $f(x,y)= ||(x-1,y-2)||$

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I think I would take $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and move the vertex where I wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A norm cannot be used, since that is a function $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$.

Your example $f(x,y)=(|x−1|,|x−2|)$ is not differentiable in $\{x=1\}\cup\{y=2\}$.

The easiest way is to make an artificial discontinuity:

$$f(x,y) := \left\{\begin{matrix}
(0,0) \text{ if } (x,y) \ne (1,2)\\
(1,1) \text{ if } (x,y) = (1,2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

If $f$ is not continuous at a certain point, it can't be differentiable there.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely **yes**.

The function you gave is great since the euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^2$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Your example

$$f(x,y)=\vert\vert(x-1,y-2)\vert \vert$$

works.